# Wrong that in a hypothesis test, one relies on the sample to formulate the hypotheses

Tags: probability, statistics, hypothesis-testing, sampling

I have been told that it is wrong that in a hypothesis test, one relies on the sample to formulate the hypotheses. Why is it that false?

Comment: What do you mean by "relies on the sample"? You formulate a hypothesis given a model.

Comment: I mean by sample that a small part or quantity intended to show what the whole is like.

Comment: If you want to test $\mu$ against $10$ and $\bar x$ turns out to be $11$ the alternative hypothesis must be $H_1\colon \mu >10$.  Otherwise $H_0$ will never be rejected.